# Regex expression that selects only specific word

Tags: regex, sublimetext3

Welcome guys, I am just new to this community!

Here is the case, I am having some strings like these

> thatisanappleaaa
>
> thatisanappleaaa bad
>
> thatisanappleaaa.bad
>
> thatisanapplebadaaa
>
> thatisanbadappleaaa
>
> thatisanbadbadappleaaa
>
> badthatisanappleaaa

and trying to use Sublime Text 3 Find and replace function to achieve the following (note that only the first line is being replaced)

> thatisanorangeaaa
>
> thatisanappleaaa bad
>
> thatisanappleaaa.bad
>
> thatisanapplebadaaa
>
> thatisanbadappleaaa
>
> thatisanbadbadappleaaa
>
> badthatisanappleaaaa

Is there a regex that filters "apple" in "thatisanappleaaa"(which is line one) only without the presence of "bad" in any position (except between "apple") in the string, given that the string "bad" does not change every time it appears?

Comment: I'm not sure this can be done with Sublime Text... it seems that Sublime Text doesn't support variable-length negative lookbehinds, so you can't do `(?<!bad.*)apple(?!.*bad)`.

Comment: I've come to the same conclusion as @smarx.

Comment: thanks guys for helping out, @smarx's regex did a perfect job in multiple testing sites. Guess I have to find my good apples in other text editors

Answer (score 0):

Try

(\w+)apple(\w+).*

will select all text wrapped around apple

if you want to select text trailing after apple use

apple(\w+).*

Comment: thanks for the response! It selects all the lines but the scenario is only selecting string "apple" without "bad" around it

Answer (score 0):

After reading your description I'm assuming you want to replace the word `apple` only in sentences which do not have any occurrences of the word `bad`.

I've used a regex which uses a negative lookahead and used parentheses to capture `apple` which can then be replaced with any word, in your case `orange`.

Regex: `^(?!.*bad).*(apple)`

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/bC4qN9/2)

Comment: thanks for response! The suggested regex is able to select 'line one' but i need to select only string "apple".

Comment: @m.x9082 If you notice on the side of the demo I provided in the 'Match Information' section, ONLY `apple` is matched by the parentheses. You can replace this matched parentheses with any word of your choice depending on the language you are using.

Comment: thanks! Now I notice your regex works in web, however when I plug it in Sublime Text 3 it selects from the beginning of the string to the end of "apple"(which is "thatisanapple"), and when I replace it with orange, the whole line of string becomes "orangeaaa".